# Frame Duplication with Changing transparancy and colors

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes, graph-editor, timeline

[image]Is there a way to Change the colors and transparency of previous and post frames using the duplication frames, in object properties?

Comment: what do you mean by saying duplication? did you animate (I keystroke over those properties) the color and the transparency in the properties editor, and then duplicated (Shift+D) the keys in the dopesheet?

Comment: If you goto object properties tab and the duplication dropdown, and click frames. In 2.8 its called instances. This will show duplicate the object along its entire motion path.

Comment: Wow, I've never knew such a feature is there. Thanks. Sadly, I cannot help.

Comment: Are you looking for an Animation Nodes solution?

Comment: Ill take an animation nodes solution, Im unsure if there is a non animation nodes solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct an action from the target object and delay it with the required amount. Then instance the target object and transform it based on the delayed action. Then just set the the color of the object as you wish, in this case, I change the hue based on their offset amount:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: this did not work for me, double checked it a few times, maybe you can look at it for me. check out updated screen shot

Comment: @NickSieben Well you aren't using the colors we generated in your materials. The colors are stored in vertex color layers, so you have to use the *Attribute* node with the attribute `Col`.

Comment: Do you know of a way to change the opacity so the previous instances fade away? Google hasn’t turned anything up.

Comment: @NickSieben Just add another vertex color layer, call it `alpha` , color it as you wish, and use it with another attribute node.